# pbdApply fails with vector returns from FUN

Tags: r

I'm trying to parallelize some trend calculations using the R pbdMPI package. I can't get the *apply functions to work with vector returns from the function to be applied. An example below, with two optional return() statements with the scalar one (commented out) working, vector (uncommented) not. For simplicity's sake there are no calculations, the problem becomes apparent just by returning constant values.

```
library(pbdMPI, quietly = TRUE)

testdata <- matrix(runif(100, 1, 10), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

rowlm <- function(x.row){
   return(c(1,2,3)) # this won't work
#  return(1) # this will work
}

testresults <- pbdApply(testdata, 1, rowlm, pbd.mode="mw")
comm.print(dim(testresults))
```

The problem is that the dimensions of the resulting object are incorrect, which I would assume the pbdApply to take care of. The error message is as follows:

Error in dim(ret) <- dim(X)[MARGIN] :
dims [product 10] do not match the length of object [30]

I have tried returning lists and matrices, always with the same result. If the return value is anything but a scalar, it will fail with the same error message. The same code just using one core and normal apply() works just as intended, except for the weird transposing of the results by apply which is trivial to fix.

The code is run on a cluster using sbatch with --ntasks-per-node=4 and --nodes=1.

Thanks! -mja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the behavior you are expecting will be produced by using the mode of "dist". This looks like an `sapply` sort of result, i.e "simplified2array"=TRUE:

```
> testresults <- pbdApply(testdata, 1, rowlm, pbd.mode="dist")
> comm.print(dim(testresults))
[1]  3 10
> testresults
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
```

You could get an `lapply` sort of result if the function returned a list.

```
 testresults
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you! This completely fixes the issue at the level described by my example. And should be applicable to the real code with some extensions. "mw" was used instead of "dist" so that the rather large data was only read by the master (source) rank and I wanted to have it distributed automatically, but of course trying to simplify the question, lost that aspect. But I should be able to scatter and gather separately and use "dist", as "mw" won't work. Thanks!